# dudas sobre tiempo de respuesta json ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Tengo una query en la cual consulto un registro la cual la hago con ajax y obtengo los datos en json. ahora mi preguntas es como podría optimizar el tiempo de respuesta ya que por ejemplo la consulta se demora como 4 segundos, la tabla a la que consulto tiene diez filas, entonces mi pregunta es si se podría optimizar la consulta o el código

La consulta ejecutada directamente en phpmyadmin se demora 0.0006 seg

**Javascript**

```
  function datos_factura(){
           var parametros =
    {
     "operacion":"datos_factura",
     "numero" : $.trim($("#nro_factura").val()),
    }
    $.ajax({

        data: parametros,
        url: 'controlador_factura.php',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype:'json',
        async:true,
        success: function (response){

          $(".busqueda2").addClass("hide");

          console.log("ejecute datos factura");
         $(".busqueda").addClass("hide");
         console.log(response.rut_persona);

          $("#fecha").val(response.fecha);
           $("#lst_pago").val(response.id_pago);
           $("#lst_categoria").val(response.id_area);
           lst_curso(response.id_area,response.folio);

         },beforeSend: function() {
          $(".busqueda2").text("Buscando espere...");
          $(".busqueda2").removeClass("hide");
         },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("pongase en contacto con el programador: "+errorThrown);
         }
    });
}
```

**Controlador php**

```
<?php

  include_once 'clases/clase_participante.php';
  include_once 'clases/clase_persona.php';
  include_once 'clases/clase_usuario.php';
  include_once 'clases/clase_factura.php';
  error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
  $obj=new Participantes();
                                  $per= new Personas();
                     $usu= new Usuario();
                     $obj3= new Factura();
                     switch ($_POST["operacion"]) {
                        case 'datos_factura':
                        $datos=$obj3->datos_factura($_POST["numero"]);
                        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
                        echo json_encode($datos);
                        break;

                    case 'datos_participante':
                        $obj3->rut=$_POST["rut"];
                        $datos=$obj3->datos_participante();
                        header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
                        echo json_encode($datos);
                        break;

                    case 'grabar':
                        $resultado=0;
                        $per->rut=$_POST["rut"];
                        $per->nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
                        $per->ap_m=$_POST["ap_m"];
                        $per->ap_p=$_POST["ap_p"];
                        $per->celular=$_POST["celular"];
                        $per->correo=$_POST["correo"];
                        $per->nro_calle=$_POST["nro_calle"];
                        $per->calle=$_POST["calle"];
                        $per->id_comuna=$_POST["id_comuna"];
                        $per->fecha=$_POST["f_nac"];
                        if ($obj3->validar_curso_empresa($_POST["rut_empresa"],$_POST["folio"])==0) {
                                    if($obj3->validar_curso_par($_POST["rut"],$_POST["folio"])==0){
                                       if ($usu->validar_rut($_POST["rut"])==0){
                                           $resultado=$per->insertar_persona(1);
                                           $obj->insertar_tipo($_POST["rut"],$_POST["id_tipo"]);

                                           if (!empty($_POST["rut_empresa"])){
                                               $obj->insertar_per_empresa($_POST["rut_empresa"],$_POST["rut"]);

                                            }
                                            echo $resultado;

                            }else{
                            $resultado=$per->modificar_persona();
                            $obj->modificar_empresa_par($_POST["rut_empresa"],$_POST["rut"],$_POST["empresa_persona"]);
                            $obj->modificar_tipo($_POST["id_tipo"],$_POST["persona_participante"]);
                            }
                            //insertar factura
                            $obj3->rut=$_POST["rut"];
                            $obj3->rut_empresa=$_POST["rut_empresa"];
                            $obj3->nro_fac=$_POST["nro_fac"];
                            $obj3->id_pago=$_POST["id_pago"];
                            $obj3->id_tipo=$_POST["id_tipo"];
                            $obj3->fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
                            $obj3->costo=$_POST["costo"];
                            $obj3->folio=$_POST["folio"];
                            $obj3->grabar_participante();
                        }else{
                            echo 11;
                        }
                        }else{echo 20;}
                    break;           
                }
                 ?>
```

**Función de la clase php**

```
function datos_factura($nro){
 $sql="SELECT cf.nro_factura as nro,(select df.folio from detalle_factura where df.nro_factura=nro limit 1)as folio,cf.id_pago
      ,DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha,cg.id_generico,cg.id_area
                                 from  comprobante_factura cf
                                 INNER JOIN detalle_factura df on  cf.nro_factura=df.nro_factura
                                 INNER JOIN cursos c on c.folio=df.folio
                                 INNER JOIN curso_generico cg on 
              cg.id_generico=c.id_generico
              where cf.nro_factura=$nro"";
 $resultado=mysqli_query($this->conexion,$sql);
 $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
 return($datos); 
}
```

**Consola de google chrome**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar el sentido de tu SELECT en la función `datos_factura`  y en qué usas la variable `$nro` que recibe dicha función ?

Comment: @A.Cedano no me di cuenta que me faltaba eso

Comment: Aquí el problema no se debe a la consulta en sí, si no en el tiempo requerido en formar el JSON, deberás consultar qué partes de tu controlador son las más lentas a tavés de algún profiling, pero me atrevo a decir que el cuello de botella está en `json_encode`

Comment: @EduenSarceño y como podria hacer eso

Comment: @josemigueljara A manera de prueba elimina las llamadas a json_encode, itera manualmente la respuesta de la base de datos para ver si efectivamente el cuello de botella está en `json_encode`, si la respuesta es afirmativa, entonces crea tu propio encoder a json, tomando en cuenta el rendimiento del mismo

Comment: @EduenSarceño hice un nuevo controlador solo con el metodo que necesitaba y la respuesta fue de 1.2 segundos quisas pudo haber sido donde se cargaban varias clases en el controlador

Comment: @EduenSarceño ya se cual era el problema, pasa que instanciaba cada clase al principio del controlador entonces puse los objetos en un en ucase aparte

Comment: @josemigueljara si encontraste la solución a tu pregunta, deberías ponerlo como respuesta (con algo más de detalle) en lugar de como comentario. Los comentarios no se indexan y no se pueden buscar, lo que haría difícil para otro usuario con un problema parecido encontrar tu respuesta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si ahora la redactare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre cual era el error al principio del controlador llamaba a todas las clases creando objetos de tal manera que como eran varias todas se cargaban, es por esto que la creación de objetos para llamar clases las hago solamente cuando las necesito realmente de esta forma se ahorra tiempo en la ejecución del código